# Links in pie charts for Highcharts.js

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I would like the user to be directed to a specific part of the page when they click on a section of the pie chart. I'm getting an error that reads `{"error": "Please use POST request"}` on click.

http://jsfiddle.net/alliwagner/Saa4E/10/

Right now the blue section should jump down to "Commodities" on click.

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Pointy/Saa4E/13/) is an update to your jsfiddle.

The changes I had to make were:

- The "click" handler has `this` bound to a data point as a structure maintained by that library. In order to get the URL, you have to look at the "config" property of the data point and then grab element 2 of that array.
- I had to stash the `this` in the event handler so that the timeout handler could get it.
- I added a "preventDefault()" call to the event handler, but that might not be necessary.

Comment: Pointy, Thanks so so much! Worked like a charm... Very much appreicated :)

Comment: No problem, good luck!  That looks like a nice charting package too.

Comment: Yeah,  highcharts is super robust and easy (enough) to work with. Ive been really happy with it thus far (so has the client!)

Comment: @Pointy How to open link in the new window? I tried to put <a href="http://www.w3schools.com/">Visit W3Schools</a> in the link but it won't work. How to make the link open in new windows?

Comment: @Narazana well first, [be careful with w3schools](http://w3fools.com). Then, you should post a completely new question to get an answer; that question has nothing to do with this answer or its question.

Comment: @Pointy What I'm trying to do is similar to the question above except that the link will be open in the new windows when user clicks on a section of the pie chart. Sorry for the misleading comment above.

Answer (score 5):

The solution posted here no longer works as of version 3 of Highcharts

This works better

```
series: [{
    type: 'pie',
    name: 'overall',
    point: {
        events: {
            click: function(e) {
                location.href = e.point.url;
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        }
    },
    data: [
        {name: 'Not Tested', color: '#FFA850', y: 87, url: 'http://my_site1.com'},
        {name: 'Fail', color: '#FF2929', y: 2, url: 'http://my_site2.com'},
        {name: 'Pass', color: '#31FF4F', y: 32, url: 'http://my_site3.com'}
    ]
}]
```